# I can't get passport remember me working with express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passport remember me with express router. It's not working properly when I use:

```
router.route("/login).(someController().postlogin)
```

Then the authentication is not working as it doesn't generate the token.

But when I use the `app.post` then it's working.

Working code:

```
  app.post('/login',  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),async function(req, res, next) {
    // issue a remember me cookie if the option was checked
    if (!req.body.remember_me) { return next(); }

    var token = utils.randomString(64);
    try {
        const tokenData= await Token.create({ userId: req.user.id, token });
        res.cookie('remember_me', token, { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 604800000 }); // 7 days
      return next();
    } catch (error) {
        return next();  
    }
  },
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

But when I use the same code with router it's not working:

```
        postLogin: (req, res) => {
             passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),async function(req, res, next) {
    // issue a remember me cookie if the option was checked
    if (!req.body.remember_me) { return next(); }

    var token = utils.randomString(64);
    try {
        const tokenData= await Token.create({ userId: req.user.id, token });
        res.cookie('remember_me', token, { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 604800000 }); // 7 days
      return next();
    } catch (error) {
        return next();  
    }
  },
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
               
    
        },
```

I am using:

- http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-remember-me/
- http://www.passportjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

finally it's working but there is a new issue ,`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` cant understand how to fix it.

```
postLogin: async (req, res, next) => {

  // passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' })
  passport.authenticate('local', {}, async function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(error);
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      console.log("NO USER");
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }

    if (req.body.remember_me) {
      var token = utils.randomString(64);
      await Token.create({
        token: token,
        userId: user.id,
      }).then((token) => {
        if (token) {
          res.cookie('remember_me', token.token, { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 604800000 }); // 7 days
          return next();
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        return done(err);
      })
    }


    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
},
```